# Grey out all images other than active hover image

Tags: hover

I'm trying to achieve an effect whereby I have 6 images, all of which are in full colour by default but when I hover on one, I want that image to stay as it is but all the other 5 images to fade out slightly. The purpose being to highlight the image the user is hovered on.

I have a basic 'grayscale on hover' set up here [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VYAaN/)

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target='_blank'><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/nkhruktyb/image.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target='_blank'><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8r349tm77/image.jpg"></a>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target='_blank'><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z8btp4j37/image.jpg"></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target='_blank'><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/d6ljf2ylf/image.jpg"></a>
            <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target='_blank'><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/fg9npu7j7/image.jpg"></a>
                <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target='_blank'><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/bstwjrzc3/image.jpg"></a>
```

CSS

```
img:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change the class?

Edit: Now the siblings will turn grey

```
 $('img').hover(function() {
      $(this).siblings().toggleClass('grayscale');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Now resolved after playing around, this works.

HTML

```
<img src="http://s29.postimg.org/nkhruktyb/image.jpg" class="fade_hov">
<img src="http://s29.postimg.org/8r349tm77/image.jpg" class="fade_hov">
<img src="http://s29.postimg.org/z8btp4j37/image.jpg" class="fade_hov">
<img src="http://s29.postimg.org/d6ljf2ylf/image.jpg" class="fade_hov">
<img src="http://s29.postimg.org/fg9npu7j7/image.jpg" class="fade_hov">
<img src="http://s29.postimg.org/bstwjrzc3/image.jpg" class="fade_hov">
```

CSS

```
.fade_hov{
background: #fff;
} 

.fade{
opacity: .5;
}
```

JS

```
$('.fade_hov').hover(function(){
                    $(this).siblings().addClass('fade');
            }, function(){
                    $(this).siblings().removeClass('fade');
            });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YwKVt/22/)

Comment: The only thing with this answer is it won't allow me to do the same with image hyperlinks, it only seems to work with images that have no hyperlink. Example here http://jsfiddle.net/YwKVt/23/

Comment: Answered my own question http://jsfiddle.net/YwKVt/24/ Now need to work out why the jsfiddle is perfect but it doesn't work in my project....